# É obrigatório passar pelo Mutator/Accessor?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

Acabei de encarar um problema no **Laravel 5.1**.

Imagine que eu tenha o seguinte:

### Model

```
class User extends Model{

   # Mutator

   public function getNomeUpperAttribute(){
       return strtoupper($this->attributes['nome']);
   }

}
```

### Controller

```
public function index(){

   $user = User::find(1);

   $user->nome_upper;

}
```

#### Retorno

> NOME EM MAIÚSCULO

Mas vamos supor que eu fiz um JOIN pelo Eloquent e **não** selecione o campo *nome* da tabela *Users*.

```
public function index(){

   $user = User::join('enderecos', 'enderecos.id_user', '=', 'users.id')
                 ->select('rua', 'bairro', 'numero', 'cep')
                 ->where('id_user', '=', 1)
                 ->first();

}
```

Quando isso acontece a página dá um erro:

> undefined index 'nome';

Isso acontece porque ele entra na função que defini no Model *Users*.

Para não dar erro, tenho que fazer uma verificação assim:

```
public function getNomeUpperAttribute(){
    if(array_key_exists('nome', $this->attributes))
        return strtoupper($this->attributes['nome']);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Mas imagine que eu tenha vários Accessors para customizar diversos campos. Eu teria que fazer essa verificação em todos.

A pergunta é:

#### Isso é realmente necessário ? Não tem outro jeito ?

Comment: nesse caso não é `mutators` é `serialization` se eu não estiver enganado? estou baseando na grafia !!!

Comment: Nesse caso, não é *Mutators*, e sim [*Accessors*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma pequena correção: Isso não se chama *Mutator*, e sim *Accessor*.

Mutator é para definir o atributo, Accessor é para acessar.

Em alguns frameworks que têm a mesma finalidade que um *Accessor* provê, isso é chamado de *Virtual Field*.

O uso do do Accessor se limita a casos onde você precisa de uma formatação específica de um determinado campo da sua tabela. Há possibilidades de retornar outros tipos de informações, mas geralmente você vai querer usá-los para trabalhar com dados específicos da tabela.

Sendo assim, sempre que você precisar formatar determinado campo do resultado de uma consulta, você vai precisar que ele seja selecionado via `select`.

No seu caso, o erro `Undefined Index`ocorre porque o campo não foi selecionado.

Respondando a sua pergunta: Sim, você precisaria de verificar todas as vezes, o que não meu ver não é um problema, já que você define um método apenas uma vez, mas reutiliza em toda sua aplicação.

Outro detalhe: Ao invés de usar `$this->attributes['valor']`, você pode usar `$this->valor` diretamente.

```
public function getNomeUpperAttribute(){
   return strtoupper($this->nome);
}
```

A única observação que faço no caso de você querer usar a propriedade diretamente, ao invés da propriedade `attributes` é que, se você definir um método com o mesmo nome do campo que você está acessando, isso vai gerar uma *recursividade infinita*.

Exemplo:

```
public function getNomeAttribute(){
   // Gera recursão, pois internamente será chamado o mesmo método
   return strtoupper($this->nome); 
}
```

Então, a dica de usar a propriedade diretamente, só vale se o nome do Accessor for diferente do atributo acessado.